# Should both tables have user_id, even though one-to-one relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have got two tables **subscriptions** and **payments**. These two are related with a *one-to-one* relation. Basically every **subscription** belongs to a **user** (via `user_id`) and every **payment** belongs to a **user** as well. (yes I know) Because they are bond with a *one-to-one* relation, there is logically no need that both carry the user_id row. But it's vital for  both that they show the **user** they belong to and I am not sure. Should I rely on that bond or would it be okay that both keep their `user_id` (even they will be same) ? This is more of a theoretical question but a little example of the tables are below.

```
payments
id   user_id   paymentstuff  ...
1    42         ...
2    16         ...

subscriptions 
id   payment_id   user_id   subscriptionstuff  ...
1    1            42        ...
2    2            16        ...

users
id   name   lname userstuff  ...
16   john   doe   ...
42   jane   foe   ...
```

**PS:** As @jeroen and @ThomasSmyth mentioned, a **user** can have **many** subscriptions and a **user** can have **many** payments as well. So the user part has a *one-to-many* relation to payment and subscriptions.

Comment: Are you really saying that a single user can only have 1 subscription and make 1 payment ever? That sounds very unlikely and contradictory as it's not really a subscription if it's a one-time thing.

Comment: @jeroen actually you are right a user can/should have many (past subscriptions etc). I will edit it. Thx.

Comment: @Skeletor, what about multiple payments? For example, it's quite likely that I pay more than once for a subscription, if it's only for a certain time period (like Spotifiy Premium). It seems you most likely have a one to many relationship for users to subs and users to payments and then a 1 to 1 between subs and payments (if one payment can only buy 1 subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jeron said your data models seems wrong! But in case you have such conditions your tables could be like these:

```
User model {
    id, username, email
}
Payment model {
    user_id, payment_stuff
}
Subscription model {
    user_id, subscribe_stuff
}
```